# jquery method in another file not found

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a file- "Site.js" with the following method:

```
function Init() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //some init actions here
  });
}
function jQuery.fn.DivToggle(div) {
  $(div).toggle('fast');
  //some other animation code here
}
```

in my Index.cshtml file (I'm using asp.net mvc), I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Site.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        Init();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get this error when I run the project:
"Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Init' is undefined"

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: do you have all of the functions in Site.js wrapped in a `$(function () { all functions here });` tag? if so, the `init()` function will be private an unable to call it from outside of Site.js

Comment: why document.ready is inside Init() function?

Comment: @JohnnyCraig: Nope. Just: function Init() { //code }

Comment: @DotNetter Removed document.ready, still see the same issue.

Comment: `function jQuery.fn.DivToggle(){}` <= you can't actually do that.  It should be `jQuery.fn.DivToggle=function(){}`

Comment: @Rocket, he is dealing with a syntax error. Post your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Init` is not defined because there is a syntax error in `Site.js`.

```
function jQuery.fn.DivToggle(div) {
  $(div).toggle('fast');
  //some other animation code here
}
```

You can't actually do that.  It should be:

```
jQuery.fn.DivToggle = function(div) {
  $(div).toggle('fast');
  //some other animation code here
};
```

P.S. `$(function(){` is the same as `$(document).ready(function(){`.  You don't need the `$(document).ready(function(){` inside your `Init` function.

Answer (score 1):

I think the real problem is with your DivToggle() function. You should change that code to the following:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.DivToggle = function() {
     $(this).toggle('fast');
  };
})( jQuery );
```

Then you can call DivToggle by creating a selector and calling it. So if you want to run this on all of the div tags in your page do this:

```
$('div').DivToggle();
```

Here is some documentation on creating custom plugins: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

You probably need to change the way you are calling Init() and document.ready(). Actually the Init() function isn't really doing anything right now. I think you can change your code to this and it would accomplish what you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//create the DivToggle() function
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.DivToggle = function() {
     $(this).toggle('fast');
  };
})( jQuery );

$(function () {
    //call DivToggle() on all <div> tags when the page loads
    $('div').DivToggle();
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try namespacing your javascript:

```
 StackOverflow = {

      function Init(){

      }

      return {
        Init: Init
      };
 }();
```

Call your function with

```
$(function(){
     StackOverflow.Init();
});
```

Comment: Why would this make a difference?

Comment: @Rocket I think it is a good practice to namespace your JavaScript.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `StackOverflow = (function(){...}());`?

Comment: It may be a good idea, but I don't see how it relates to the question.